# Why does VBA code fail when setting a new instance of an Outlook Application object?

Tags: vba, outlook

The first sub routine runs fine when called upon application startup, while the second does not bring up Outlook and instead takes a minute or two, culminating in an error. The only difference is that in the "set" statement, I put the word "New". I am aware that this means it is trying to open up a new instance of the Outlook client, while one is already running, but why wouldn't there be a way for the Outlook to deal with the request for a new application while one is already running, or use the new instance instead of the existing instance?

```
Sub SaveAttachment1_Initialize()
        
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
        
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SaveAttachment1_Initialize()
            
            Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
            Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
            
            Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
            Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't Outlook a single-instance application?  Not sure you can start a new instance if it's already running...

Comment: Agree with @TimWilliams - Outlook is single instance app - you should just be able to create a new object and it will link to any existing running Outlook app - or create the new one if existing one is not found

Comment: If the code is running inside Outlook, there is absolutely no reason to create a new instance of `Outlook.Application` - there is already an intrinsic `Application` variable available to the script. More than that, that `Application` will not be subject to the security prompts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in Outlook VBA, that line must be

```
Set olApp = Application
```

If not, the second one is correct. The first one makes no sense - you are assigning a variable to type (?).